# Are metal steel strings OK for classic violin?

Tags: violin

Are metal steel strings OK for classic violin? Never played violin, you know.

Comment: Can you expand on your question a little to help get the best answers? For instance, are just starting to learn the violin and you have a violin that has no strings on it? Do you have a violin teacher? Are trying to help someone else? Tell us a little more about the particular situation.

Comment: Perhaps you're getting confused by the similar association of nylon vs. steel for guitar?

Comment: Short answer: for a  beginner, yes. Long answer: There are a lot of possibilities. http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/37982/buying-nicer-violin-strings?rq=1

Comment: @ShawnStrickland I hang out with fiddle players (never classical violin players) and had assumed that all violins were steel strings. But apparently classical players do use gut strings. So the general pattern on guitar of "steel for folk nylon for classical" would appear to apply to violin too. Lets see if a violinist can shed some light. http://www.ifshinviolins.com/Articles/tabid/145/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/411/Guide-To-Choosing-and-Using-Strings-for-Violins-Violas-and-Cellos.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You'll be hard put to find non-metal steel strings.  Joking aside, a massive steel string is typical for the E string.  All the others are usually *wound* with metal but have a gut-like core.

Comment: what are the top brand strings for violin, like Earnie Ball and Dean Markley for guitar?

Answer (score 2):

This is very broad.

Classical strings, as noted in user25984's answer, are actually made of a long core (synthetic, metallic or rarely gut) and of a wound, generally of steel, sometimes of silver.

Baroque strings are gut.

> Are metal steel strings OK for classic violin?

Yes, they definitely are ok for classical violin. There is a large range of colors you can achieve by choosing this or that string set. Thomastik strings are very known strings, cheap yet producing good sound.

I personally like Vision Titanium Orchestral string sets, for their bright sound, their responsiveness and their long life time.

It should be noted, however, that the kind of influence string has on sound can take some time to be aware of.